# Get other fields as well on MIN query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named **soft** with the following fields:

```
pname, title, developin, dcost
```

Here `pname` is the name of each programmer.
`title` is the name of a developed project.
`developin` is the language used to develop the project.
`dcost` is the development cost for the project.

I need a query which will display the name of the programmer & the cheapest packages developed by them in each language.

So I tried this query:

```
SELECT developin, MIN(dcost) as 'total'
FROM software
GROUP BY developin
ORDER BY MIN(dcost)
```

With this query I get the lowest cost of each language but, **how do I display pname & title as well?**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM software s
WHERE dcost = (SELECT MIN(dcost)
               FROM software
               WHERE developin = s.developin
               GROUP BY developin)
```

**Or, with a `JOIN`:**

```
SELECT s.*
FROM software s
JOIN (SELECT developin, MIN(dcost) AS cost
      FROM software
      GROUP BY developin) s2
  ON s.developin = s2.developin AND s.dcost = s2.cost
```

I'm not sure whether it's possible without using a sub-query.

**Why just adding `, pname, title` in the `SELECT` part of your query won't work:**

Consider `MIN(dcost), MAX(dcost)` - this would get the minimum and the maximum of `dcost`. So obviously the entire returned row can't belong to the row containing `MIN(dcost)`.

Now consider `MIN(dcost), MAX(dcost), pname, title`, it would obviously not know which row to take `pname` and `title` from. And because you can add `MAX(dcost)`, SQL Server can't return `pname` and `title` from the `MIN(dcost)` row.

Yes, it *can* detect that you only use `MIN`, but it will lead to confusing and inconsistent results.

I hope that helps.

Comment: @dukeling the first query works for me & thanks for your help....i you don't mind can you please tell me where i am getting wrong...as i am in learning stage it will be great help of you if possible

Comment: thanks for your explanation....i got the difference between them....thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1):

For SQL-Server 2005 and later, you can do this using a CTE and an [aggregate window function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

```
; WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT pname, title, developin, dcost, 
           MIN(dcost) OVER (PARTITION BY developin) AS total
    FROM software
  ) 
SELECT pname, title, developin, dcost
FROM cte
WHERE dcost = total
ORDER BY total ;
```

Comment: this query also giving proper result....i tried this cte approach but not able to make it properly...now i got it where i am committing the mistake....thanks for your help

Comment: I find myself wondering whether you can use `OVER` without the CTE to get the same results. Something like `Using the OVER clause with aggregate functions` in [your link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), which, I know, is not at all the same.

Comment: You can use a derived table instead of the CTE (if that's what you are asking)

Comment: No, I mean no CTE, sub-query or derived table. Everything just in the SELECT. Maybe using some complex `OVER` query. It probably isn't possible, but that's what I'm asking.

Answer (score -1):

Is that you want

```
select Pname,developin, MIN(dcost)as 'total'
from software
group by developin,Pname
order by MIN(dcost)
```

Comment: javed khan sorry to say that but this query will not give me the desired output.from my query i am getting following result      c 700
cpp 1200
assembly3000
cobol 3500
pascal 4500
basic 6000
dbase 20000
oracle 85000        i just want another column which shows me the name of the person ie pname

Comment: select Pname,developin, MIN(dcost)as 'total' ... PName is added in the query...you must be getting three columns now....how is it possible, when there are 3 column names in the select query, and you are still getting 2

Comment: @qasimjaved i am getting all the 3 columns from your query but it does not give me the desired o/p i want that it will dispaly the name,developin along with the cheapest package developed in each langauge

Answer (score -1):

Something like this might do it.

```
select pname, developin, title, dcost
from software join
(select pname name, developin lang, min(dcost) mincost
from software
group by pname, developin) temp on name = pname 
and developin = lang
and dcost = mincost
```

Comment: @dan bracuk sorry to say that but this query also not provideing me the correct output

Comment: Now that I've fixed the syntax (oops) it should provide the results for the question you asked.  If it's not the correct output, edit your question and provide some sample data and query results.

Comment: Your query returns "For each programmer and language, the cheapest project", which *it seems* is what the question asks. But the code in the question is "For each language, the cheapest project". You may want to point this out in the answer. And you should also say `@prags`, otherwise your comment won't trigger a notification.